# how do you open a github repository into a browser tab to have a functional game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know the question may seem simple but I cant figure it out.
I need help with being able to open a few files that are in JS, CSS and HTML preferably to a browser. Here is the github repository https://github.com/999Solid/Gameforschool

Comment: Have [you cloned the repo](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository) or copied the raw contents of each file in that repo into local HTML/JS/CSS files on your computer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Comment: If you mean that the files are used as a site and you see them in browser online (in other word you deploy the files) maybe reading [this article](https://medium.com/@erickcodes/creating-and-deploying-a-static-website-using-github-pages-a634a588ed7d) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

- in **Spel.html** in line 6: update the **href** to **Spel.css**  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Spel.css">`
- also in line 41: update **src** to **Spel.js** `<script src="Spel.js"></script>`

you may want to rename `Spel.html` to `index.html` so it becomes the default page for the link instead of using
https://999solid.github.io/Gameforschool/Spel.html
it can be just:
https://999solid.github.io/Gameforschool/